# No template found for UsersController#create, rendering head :no_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

OK, previously I had a problem with a no template error from users#create, now it complete 200 OK however does not redirect at all.  Below is my edited users_controller.rb

I have a Signup, Login, Logout rails application with users as a resource.  I am trying to save the first user in the database so I can then login but this error is server output when I try to "users#new" and "users#create"  the full error is below, then my users_controller.rb and views/users -> new.html.erb

```
No template found for UsersController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

users_controller.rb

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if (@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email]))
    flash[:success] = "User already exists."
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash[:success] = "New User created."
      redirect_to '/layouts/application'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |f| %>
<p> Username:</br> <%= f.text_field :username %> </p>
<p> Email:</br> <%= f.text_field :email %> </p>
<p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password%></p>

<%= f.submit "Signup" %>
<% end %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<ul class="Signup_Errors">
<% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
  <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Do I have to have another html.erb file?  And how can I tell what that has to be?  Sorry for the obvious question, newb here.

Comment: You are not redirecting to any action if user is not present

Comment: So, rails end up trying to render the `create.html.haml`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per your code if the `User` is not present it will not enter in the if block. Rails end up trying to find `create.html` as the current action is `create`.

To avoid this you must redirect it somewhere or render a template which you have done in the next `if` and `else` but it's not executing.

The condition is not letting it redirect to anywhere. Try moving the if block out like this.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if User.exists?(email: params[:email]) # I think this should be `user_params[:email]` instead of `params[:email]`
    flash[:error] = "User already exists." 
    redirect_to 'whereever/you/want/to/redirect' and return
  end
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    flash[:success] = "New User created."
    redirect_to '/layouts/application'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened because someone derped and nested two `format.html`s, like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    format.html {}
  end
end
```